# TypeError: fs.writeFileSync is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Trying to use fs in next.js, but it gives me that error:

> TypeError: fs.writeFileSync is not a function

my `package.json` includes:

```js
resolve: {
    fallback: {
        "fs": false
    },
  }
```

This is file where i try to use `fs`:

```js
let fs: any = require('fs')

let users = require('../../public/data/monitoring.json');

export const incidentsRepo = {
    getAll: () => users,
    getById: (id: number) => users.find((x: any) => x.id.toString() === id.toString()),
    find: (x: any) => users.find(x),
    create
};

function create(user: any) {
    user.id = Date.now()
    users.push(user);
    saveData();
}

function saveData() {
    fs.writeFileSync('./public/data/monitoring.json', JSON.stringify(users, null, 4));
}
```

And when i try to click on button that hooks that `create` method, error comes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to move my `fs` function call to `/pages/api` folder not to just a component, cuz browser can't handle with `fs` and it says that `/pages/api/` is running not in browser, so it helped me